# The LaTeX raw texts appear in wikipedia in my chrome browser. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: latex3

Does anyone know why this happens? I didn't have any problems until now, then this happens suddenly. My computer is MacBook Pro with Mojave version 10.14.6. I googled a lot, but it seems like no one has ever asked this question before. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a MathJax/Javascript problem, which isn't LaTeX (and definitely isn't latex3).  Unfortunately, that makes it off topic for this site.

Comment: Sorry, this is the wrong site to ask this. Perhaps try https://webapps.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com. Though that happens to me with a very slow connection or a particularly large page which takes long to load. It goes back to normal once the page is fully loaded

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for your help. I need found the answer @ https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78679/my-browsers-display-math-formulae-in-wikipedia-pages-in-latex-format-rather-than . Thanks!